# .htaccess redirect to subfolder and hide in uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, vhosts

I want to redirect every request for:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/customer/
```

to

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/customer/httpdocs/web/
```

still continuing to show `http://subdomain.domain.com/customer` in the browser and using a .htaccess file located in "customer" folder.

This is my actual .htaccess, redirect works but browsers show the full path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ httpdocs/web [L]
```

Comment: This looks like a cached response - make sure your browser cache is clear. Is this subdomain located in a subdirectory off the parent domain? If so, does the parent directory also have a .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm clearing firefox cache at every htaccess mod, sure it is not. The subdomain is located, respecting plesk9 structure, in this way:

/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomains/subdomain/ and there's no other .htaccess

Comment: "every request" - Do you mean `/customer/<anything>` to the corresponding `<anything>` in the other directory?

Comment: It's just that your current `RewriteRule` would not "redirect" `/customer/<anything>` (only `/customer`), but you said it "works" - which makes me wonder if something else is going on. Also, your current rule should not trigger an external redirect, which you say it is doing? The external redirect would only happen if you had previously tested with the `R=301` flag (by accident) - this would then be cached.

Comment: Ok, you got it. The "anything" does not really work. If I call /customer/ it works because there's another .htaccess in the subdomain folder (/customer/httpdocs/web) with a rewrite rule to index.html, but If I call /customer/index.html it does not work. How I change to make "anything" working?

Comment: @anubhava it finally works! please make an answer so I will set as accepted

Comment: ok great, I have converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rewrite anything for your subdomain you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ httpdocs/web/$1 [L]
```

`^$` will only rewrite landing page whereas `.*` will match all the URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try below entry:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/customer/(.*)$ /customer/httpdocs/web/$1 [PT,L,QSA]`

Comment: It does not work (forbidden).. I have to put the .htaccess in /customer/ folder already, so I think that the origin should be ./ and not /customer/

Comment: Can you try adding the entry in virtual host and see if that helps ?